# LINQ from x in Table_name?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am working on asp net core and while handling data I have to use LINQ.
I don't understand the `from x in Table_name` part in a statement, for example.

```
from p in Products
let spanishOrders = p.OrderDetails.Where (o => o.Order.ShipCountry == "Spain")
where spanishOrders.Any()
orderby p.ProductName
select new
{
    p.ProductName,
    p.Category.CategoryName,
    Orders = spanishOrders.Count(), 
    TotalValue = spanishOrders.Sum (o => o.UnitPrice * o.Quantity)
}
```

What is this `from p in Products` why is the "from p" required and different from the SQL way of just using `From Table_Name` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you man

Comment: What part is hard to understand? from p in Products is just like "select p.Something, ...  from products p".

Comment: @CetinBasoz I just started with LINQ that was my suspicion just wanted to confirm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq knows two types of syntaxes: method syntax and query syntax.

Method syntax follows the standard syntax of your computer language; query syntax is the form you currently use.

Both syntaxes use an input sequence: the collection of items of which you want to select one or more elements from. In C# this sequence implements either `IEnumerable<MyClass>` or `IQueryable<MyClass>`. Every element of this sequence is one object of `MyClass` or derived from it.

> From the sequence of all students, give me the `Addresses` of the students that were born before 2000-1-1

```
DateTime limitDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
IEnumerable<Student> students = GetAllStudents();
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    if (student.Birthday < limitDate)
       addresses.Add(student.Address);
}
```

I deliberately didn't use `var`, so you'd be fully aware of the types

Note that you have an identifier for the complete collection: `students` and an identifier for every element in the collection: `student`.

Something similar happens when you perform a LINQ query: you need identifiers to identify the input collection (source), and one to identify every element of your source:

A similar query in method syntax:

> From the sequence of all students, give me the Id / Name / Address of the students that were born before 2000-1-1

```
var addresses = students                            // from the sequence of Students
    .Where(student => student.Birtday < limitDate)  // keep only with BirthDay < LimitDate
    .Select(student => new              // from every remaining Student make one new object
    {                                   // with properties 
         Id = student.Id
         FirstName = student.FirstName,
         LastName = student.LastName,
         Address = student.Addres,
    });
```

Query syntax:

```
from student in students
where student.Birthday < limitDate
select new
{
     Id = student.Id,
     FirstName = student.FirstName,
     LastName = student.LastName,
     Address = student.Address,
};
```

You see in both syntaxes the same usage of identifiers for the complete collection (`students`) and for every element in the collection (`student`). They have the same meaning as `students` and `student` in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

A query expression must begin with a from clause. Additionally, a query expression can contain sub-queries, which also begin with a from clause. The from clause specifies the following:

The data source on which the query or sub-query will be run.

A local range variable that represents each element in the source sequence.

Both the range variable and the data source are strongly typed. The data source referenced in the from clause must have a type of IEnumerable, IEnumerable, or a derived type such as IQueryable.

In the example, "Products" is the data source and "p" is the range variable. 
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause)